# Is standalone angular UI grid is possible?

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I was wondering whether a Angular UI grid standalone is possible.

All of the examples use `$http.get` which seem to need a server for angular to work.

Please help me with creating a desktop or standalone app using this technology.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. On the [UI-Grid site](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/207_importing_data), they provide this example. If you grab a test CSV file, you will see that you can upload it in this [sample plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xR6BlfvWiEtV3ldhmEMw?p=info) from that page. I was going to post as an answer, but not sure this can count as a product of research alone.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Brian

Comment: Is that what you were looking for? Reading again, I can't tell if you were shooting for that, or just for static data. I interpreted desktop/standalone to be spreadsheet type work, however I am realizing that I looked too far to one side.

Comment: Yes, Brian..Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The examples using a $http.get are pulling data from a ReST service, if you want to, you can assign your own data to the grid data through  $scope.gridOptions.data = (location of data).

Comment: Can location be of same folder? If I give sample.json it doesn't work

Comment: Smil can you please explain with a code snippet or an example in plnkr.co or here?

Comment: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/112_swapping_data Look at how they assigned data in this example

Comment: This answer does not account for using a file to populate the grid.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a file to populate the ui-grid you will still have to perform a GET. Smil's example references assigning data to the scope inside of a javascript file, which if you need to perform a update/refresh of data you'll have to update the javascript file.

Look at https://electron.atom.io/ if you need help in creating a desktop app with HTML, CSS & JavaScript.